# How to obtain the field from the parent serializer while serializing a nested json?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Assume this scenario

```
class SerializerA(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      batch = SerializerB(many=True)
      class Meta:
           model = ModelA
           fields = ['fieldA', 'fieldB']
 


class SerializerB(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
           model = ModelB
           fields = ['fieldC', 'fieldD']
      def validate(self, data):
          #I want to use fieldA value in this place
```

How to access the field of the JSON one level above the current level while serializing the current level?